# Windows Server 2012 BSOD after VSS Shadow Copies

Tags: windows-server-2012, vss, bsod

After the recent installation of the following KB's: KB4103730, KB4096416, KB4095872, the server would BSOD once a shadow copy starts. A sfc /scannow finds issues but also states there were some components that cannot be repaired and to check the logs. Minidump file shows Bug Check Code: 0xc000021a.

Once the mentioned KB's were removed, the BSOD stopped. How do I proceed to get assistance with this issue? Pardon my brevity as this is the first time posting an issue to this forum.

Comment: Is the server setup to create a "full/Complete" memory dump and do you have one?

Answer (score 1):

The issue resolved after reinstalling the patches. Not sure what happened the first time.